# KSP: why does TrackIR crash the first time, run the second time?

Tags: technical-issues, kerbal-space-program

I start TrackIR 4.0 software, to control a TrackIR 5 camera (KSP doesn't support TrackIR 5 software yet).  Then I start KSP and load a game.  When the spaceport appears, headtracking is inoperative nine times out of ten.  When I alt-tab to TrackIR, it has crashed (grayed-out windows, "TrackIR.exe has stopped working... details... APPCRASH in Stackhash_0a9e") .  So I quit KSP, restart TrackIR, restart KSP, and then all is well (nine times out of nine).

How can I make TrackIR work the **first** time?
(Should I buy a pre-5 camera from someone on ebay?)

KSP 1.0.  Clean optical environment: other than teensy dots from eyeglasses reflection, the camera isn't confused about which blobs are the tracking markers.  The TrackIR camera driver is 2.50.0.0, which is up to date.

**Edit:** TrackIR loosely falls under the topic "game-specific hardware."  Certainly it is marketed and used primarily as a game controller, even if it isn't specific to KSP.  So if this question is re-opened, I'll answer it as: either update the source code of KerbTrack, or buy a pre-5 TrackIR camera.

Comment: I think that this is **not** a question you should ask to us. I think that contacting TrackIR devs can be your best shot.

Comment: is purely a hardware/driver related question.

Comment: But TrackIR doesn't crash with non-KSP games.  And I'll bet you dollars to doughnuts that a dev's only answer would be "upgrade to 5.0".  http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/73184 claims support only for 4.0 cameras, so maybe working with a 5.0 camera at ALL is lucky.  Then the answer may really be either ebay a 4.0 camera, or head over to github and write a 5.0 driver myself...

Comment: (Oh dear, I'm showing my age.  Doughnuts used to cost much less than a dollar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either update the source code of the KerbTrack plugin to handle TrackIR 5.0, or buy a TrackIR camera that is older than version 5.0.